# Summary, badly formed XML comment ignored for member

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am documenting my class members in VS 2010 with Summary attribute. When I build project the XML file is build(I will use it later in developing). One of class member's summary is not included in XML file, instead error appears "Badly formed XML comment ignored for member".

The summary is text is below. I do not understand what is formatted incorrectly. Should I escape `&` character and use `%26` instead?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// URI of a web page to convert. Must start with http:// or https://. Several URI of web pages can be passed to create one PDF. For example if http://www.google.com+http://www.nytimes.com URI will be passed the two web pages will be merged into one PDF.
    /// If URI has special characters like ? or & they must be encoded.
    /// </summary>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since it's XML you have to encode special characters. Your `&` sign (has bitten me before) needs to be replaced with `&amp;`.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you should escape the `&`, as `&amp;`.

Answer (score 0):

using `&#38;` rather than `&` worked for me only.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to preserve text is to wrap it in a `<![CDATA[ ]]>` tag, for example

```
    /// <summary>
    /// URI of a web page to convert. Must start with http:// or https://. Several URI of web pages can be passed to create one PDF. For example if http://www.google.com+http://www.nytimes.com URI will be passed the two web pages will be merged into one PDF.
    /// <![CDATA[If URI has special characters like ? or & they must be encoded.]]>
    /// </summary>
```