# XML documentation missing only single property

Tags: xmldocument

I've done xml documentation in API project and provided summary of public properties (like in `<summary> </summary>` tag)
but the issue is that it is not showing documentation of only one property within the class and that too is public.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Tag opertaor has 2 options. AND &OR They both work as simple arithmetic operators. Default value : OR
    /// </summary>
    public string tagsOperator { set; get; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Group name is nullable. It is used as a filter.
    /// </summary>
    public string groupName { get; set; }
```

here is shows "Group name is nullable. It is used as a filter." written in description of groupname but it is not showing "Tag opertaor has 2 options. AND &OR They both work as simple arithmetic operators. Default value : OR" in description of tagsoperator ...
any idea why is it so? am i missing something :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to encode special characters. Your & sign needs to be replaced with

```
&amp;
```

you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349241/summary-badly-formed-xml-comment-ignored-for-member)